# How do I make this Google Script faster？

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
      function Backup() {
          var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('A'), true);
          spreadsheet.getRange('A13:H').activate();
///Copy source to target and clear it

            var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX");
            
          var source_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("A");
          var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("B");
          var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
          var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
          var values = source_range.getValues();
          target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
          source_range.clearContent();

///How do I make this Google Script faster？
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In this case, how about the following patterns?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) is used.

```js
function sample1() {
  var srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("A");
  var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange('A13:H' + srcSheet.getLastRow())
  var srcValues = srcRange.getValues();

  var dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX"); // Please set the destination Spreadsheet ID here.
  var dstSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("B");
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, srcValues.length, srcValues[0].length).setValues(srcValues);
  srcRange.clearContent();
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Sheets API is used. Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function sample2() {
  var srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("A");
  var srcRange = "'A'!A13:H" + srcSheet.getLastRow();
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(srcSpreadsheet.getId(), srcRange).values;

  var dstSpreadsheetId = "XXX"; // Please set the destination Spreadsheet ID here.
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.append({ values }, dstSpreadsheetId, "B", { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
  srcSpreadsheet.getRange(srcRange).clearContent();
}
```

### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

Answer (score 0):

To speed up, don't use `activate()` in your script. Try

```
  // source
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("A");
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange('A13:H');
  var values = source_range.getValues();

  // target
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX");
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("B");
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  
  // copy
  target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  source_range.clearContent();
```